Openvino library runtime conflict in cargo workspace
I think I have a linker conflict happening in my cargo workspace.
Some context:
My workspace consists of 3 crates:

engine: Rust crate that calls a C++ application via ffi
engine_rs: complete rust port of the above
ffi_test: Crate to compare the output of the above

engine_rs uses opencv-rs and openvino-rs with latest versions.
engine C++ code uses system opencv and a older version openvino. I have shared object files for this openvino version locally inside this crate under {cmake_src_dir}/external/openvino/lib
In ffi_test when I run test separately, commenting code for each engine, it works :thumbsup_tone1: .
The issue happens when I run both engines at the same time, and I need to do this to compare outputs:
Error: openvino_finder: OpenVINO version is too old (see https://github.com/intel/openvino-rs/issues/143): 2022.1.0-7019-cdb9bec7210-releases/2022/1")
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
test rs_engine_test ... FAILED
test cpp_engine_test ... ok

Rust engine_rs is trying to use the older openvino lib that comes in engine crate, even though they are separate crates.
I have openvino-rs  with runtime-linking  enabled. That's the furthest I got
engine build.rs:
#[cfg(all(target_os = "linux", target_arch = "x86_64"))]
fn linux_x86_64_main() {
    let cpp_engine = cmake::Config::new("./engine")
        .no_build_target(true) // Skip `make install`
        .build();

    println!("cargo:warning=engine output:{}", cpp_engine.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}/build", cpp_engine.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=engine");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=fid_engine/engine/external/openvino/lib");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=openvino");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=tbb");

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=engine/CMakeLists.txt");
}

engine_rs build.rs:
#[cfg(all(target_os = "linux", target_arch = "x86_64"))]
fn linux_x86_64_main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=/usr/lib");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=openvino_c");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=openvino");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=tbb");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=opencv_core");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=opencv_dnn");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=opencv_imgproc");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=opencv_imgcodecs");
}

I need to run both engines in the same test so I can compare the output. How can I proceed here?

Apparently this is an open issue in cargo
7880

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
